# PhantomJS script returning blank web page

Tags: php, pdf-generation, phantomjs

I'm using phantomJS to create PDFs in PHP via the shell (`shell_exec`). The script works fine on the production server, and also works fine if I plug the PhantomJS command directly into my terminal.

But it does not work when I run the script in my local dev environment. I'm wondering if there's a permissions issue involved. I won't dive into the specifics of my local environment for now since I'm guessing this is a high-level issue...

The command that is supposed to execute via `shell_exec()`:

> `/usr/local/bin/phantomjs --ignore-ssl-errors=true --debug=true ../scripts/renderTeamProfile.js https://127.0.0.1/app_dev.php/pdf/enterprise-lpc-enterprise/profile/render /private/var/tmp/pjsK2N16E.pdf`

The `php` code:

```
 public function pdfResponse($url, $script, $remote_filename)
 {
    $tempFile = tempnam('/tmp', 'pjs');
    // The extension specifies output format. Use pdf
    $tempFilePdf = $tempFile . '.pdf';
    rename($tempFile, $tempFilePdf);

    # nginx should restrict access to the localhost URL
    $urlLocal = preg_replace('/^https:..[^\/]+/', 'https://127.0.0.1', $url);

    $phantomJs = $this->container->getParameter('testsite.phantomjs_cmd');
    $command = $phantomJs.' --debug=true '.$script.' '.$urlLocal.' '.$tempFilePdf;
    $output = shell_exec($command);
    $content = file_get_contents($tempFilePdf);
    $response = new Response($content, 200);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition',
    ('inline; filename="' .    $remote_filename . '"'));
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: Do you have the same versions installed? Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: Have you tried logging the value of `$output`?

Comment: @user3584460 $output evaluates to false so that's not the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there was a different version of phantomjs installed locally vs. on the prod server. Interestingly, the bug occurred with the newer version (2.0.0) vs. 1.9.8.

Comment: You should mark your own answer as accepted, that way it won't show up in the unanswered list.